# number changed automatically to the string

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I am trying to read Excel file through apache poi. In a column I am having the data `"9780547692289". After iterating all the columns, in the output, the number is displaying like this "9.780547692289E12". I mean number changed automatically to the string(because it has'E'). I have to keep this as number only(as it is). What should I do..?

Comment: Are you setting a CellFormat on the cell? If so, are you setting the CellFormat to have a suitable Format string? And if not, why not? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably just a display setting. The "E" is just for scientific notation for displaying the number.

Answer (score 0):

//while getting values from excel   u can use this method

```
private String getCellValue(Cell cell) {
    if (cell == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
        return cell.getStringCellValue();
    } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
        return cell.getNumericCellValue() + "";
    } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
        return cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "";
    }else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
        return cell.getStringCellValue();
    }else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR){
        return cell.getErrorCellValue() + "";
    } 
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

if (cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC || cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA )

{

int i = (int)cell.getNumericCellValue();

String   cellText = String.valueOf(i);

}